# how to resolve "illegal use of LONG datatype" in JPA

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am converting Hql Query to jpql but having Error  *illegal use of LONG datatype*

```
String jpqlQuery="select entity "+
            "FROM Entity entity "+
            "WHERE  CAST(SUBSTRING(entity.nameId,2,12) AS long) >CAST( :String1 AS long) "+
            "AND CAST(SUBSTRING(entity.nameId,2,12) AS long)<= CAST( :String2 AS long) ";
```

so can anyone know how to cast as long in jpql for above query?

Comment: Since there is no `CAST` keyword in JPQL then it shouldn't really come as a surprise. There is a `TREAT` keyword, and there are references to it on the internet ... or in the JPA spec!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to use `decimal` or `NUMERIC` instead of `long` :

like this

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(entity.nameId, 2, 12) AS DECIMAL(2,12))
```

- And don't pass a String and cast it in the Query, instead you can convert it before you pass it to the query :

For example :

```
String jpqlQuery = "select entity "+
            "FROM Entity entity "+
            "WHERE  CAST(SUBSTRING(entity.nameId, 2, 12) AS DECIMAL(2,12)) > value1 "+
            "AND CAST(SUBSTRING(entity.nameId, 2, 12) AS DECIMAL(2,12)) <= value2 ";

Query query = session.createQuery(jpqlQuery);

query.setParametter("value1", Long.valueOf(value1));
query.setParametter("value2", Long.valueOf(value2));
```

Comment: @maheshjinturkar You said in your question you want to convert to JPQL. There is no CAST in JPQL. You are totally Hibernate specific still, hence HQL

Comment: @ DN1 is there any other option for cast?actually i was checking for {decimal} only by small query byt after puting cast it shows error